# Javascript divide array into ranges

Tags: javascript, statistics, range

I need a function that can divide a given dataset into x equal ranges. It should first get the min and max of the dataset, then from that it gets the spread (max - min). Then it divides this spread into x parts, and returns an array containing x numbers. The numbers represent how many numbers are in the range, and the index of the array represents the range.

My function:

```js
function getRanges(dataset, numranges)
{
    min = Math.min.apply(dataset);
    max = Math.max.apply(dataset);
    spread = max - min;
    step = spread/numranges;
    ranges = [];

    for (i=0; i<numranges; i++)
    {
        for (n=0; n<dataset.length-1; n++)
        {
            if (dataset[n] >= step*i + min   &&   dataset[n] < step*(i+1) + min)
            {
                ranges[i]++;
            }
        }
    }

    return ranges;
}
```

Input:

```
getRanges( [
0.015451195257224088,
0.05483521461643034,
0.06617379094530743,
0.07870092892661003,
0.09966687613379838,
0.10666514582416224,
0.10690839801842311,
0.11439821585323147,
0.12306810641438438,
0.12392980727994662,
0.1408540614658845,
0.15281179716445356,
0.1614029704208362,
0.1718209472324214,
0.18492944998962643,
0.19174111693616214,
0.1924469352070364,
0.201953815915777,
0.20309976786182543,
0.2178176544850601,
0.2213545989524347,
0.22550557354900477,
0.23089729892233193,
0.23819719697005529,
0.23984420754302957,
0.2429043996153234,
0.2437201992017493,
0.24773906891348088,
0.24787672203748462,
0.25129651551005683,
0.25236227381026965,
0.25555897741435185,
0.2568307873610046,
0.2579000754060184,
0.25991068215231194,
0.26076078604654973,
0.26938676930938527,
0.27137058611500353,
0.2714326441795975,
0.2764167784037549,
0.28195315820279987,
0.2846181948125861,
0.28494790062924125,
0.2955654519507425,
0.2980014993424446,
0.30091593716696113,
0.30212161416680083,
0.30658886094504534,
0.31305918674142585,
0.317928758159428,
0.3326659331080829,
0.34726651130860553,
0.3577536858416604,
0.36040942846958357,
0.3634475366141404,
0.3636502832650337,
0.37657879597026606,
0.37814949618916843,
0.38186803855924834,
0.38845503635191553,
0.3910772647246715,
0.39400632306393685,
0.4109357393771207,
0.4163410915311307,
0.41816459971235165,
0.42252764144480326,
0.43347380456325807,
0.435696281748153,
0.44301634426481185,
0.453481768706172,
0.46307154320261923,
0.4691677512037378,
0.46934557070509453,
0.4736100446708187,
0.4764587668478003,
0.4914682078649019,
0.49708883552851807,
0.4989653008464718,
0.5011285370045405,
0.5098189247039806,
0.5209596336702528,
0.5278237946925293,
0.5501036890701407,
0.5551041026696315,
0.5593579433255046,
0.5614983229767005,
0.5617926864659308,
0.5655289412257961,
0.5802908272771363,
0.5889310183452419,
0.6006524589952945,
0.624822034287017,
0.6302801026102428,
0.6498155436414438,
0.6711314255389402,
0.7097413148908829,
0.7279695179821742,
0.7805217243317325,
0.8095861819199952,
1
], 10);
```

Expected output:
`[5,12,28,17,16,12,5,3,1,1]`
Because there are 5 numbers `n >= 0 && n < 0.1`
and 12 numbers `n >= 0.1 && n < 0.2`
and 28 numbers `n >= 0.2 && n < 0.3`
etc...

Actual output:
`[]`
(not kidding)

Comment: It's a good idea to be in the habit of declaring all your local variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems:

1. You use `Math.min.apply` and `Math.max.apply` the wrong way.
2. Your `ranges` variable is an empty array so when you run `ranges[i]++`, it give `NaN`.
3. Your expected output is not correct because the `step` is not `0.1`.

Here's the working version:

```js
function getRanges(dataset, numranges)
{
    min = Math.min.apply(null, dataset);
    max = Math.max.apply(null, dataset);
    spread = max - min;
    step = spread/numranges;
    ranges = [];

    for (i=0; i<numranges; i++)
    {
        for (n=0; n<dataset.length-1; n++)
        {
            if (dataset[n] >= step*i + min   &&   dataset[n] < step*(i+1) + min)
            {
                if (!ranges[i]) ranges[i] = 0;
                ranges[i]++;
            }
        }
    }

    return ranges;
}

console.log(getRanges( [
0.015451195257224088,
0.05483521461643034,
0.06617379094530743,
0.07870092892661003,
0.09966687613379838,
0.10666514582416224,
0.10690839801842311,
0.11439821585323147,
0.12306810641438438,
0.12392980727994662,
0.1408540614658845,
0.15281179716445356,
0.1614029704208362,
0.1718209472324214,
0.18492944998962643,
0.19174111693616214,
0.1924469352070364,
0.201953815915777,
0.20309976786182543,
0.2178176544850601,
0.2213545989524347,
0.22550557354900477,
0.23089729892233193,
0.23819719697005529,
0.23984420754302957,
0.2429043996153234,
0.2437201992017493,
0.24773906891348088,
0.24787672203748462,
0.25129651551005683,
0.25236227381026965,
0.25555897741435185,
0.2568307873610046,
0.2579000754060184,
0.25991068215231194,
0.26076078604654973,
0.26938676930938527,
0.27137058611500353,
0.2714326441795975,
0.2764167784037549,
0.28195315820279987,
0.2846181948125861,
0.28494790062924125,
0.2955654519507425,
0.2980014993424446,
0.30091593716696113,
0.30212161416680083,
0.30658886094504534,
0.31305918674142585,
0.317928758159428,
0.3326659331080829,
0.34726651130860553,
0.3577536858416604,
0.36040942846958357,
0.3634475366141404,
0.3636502832650337,
0.37657879597026606,
0.37814949618916843,
0.38186803855924834,
0.38845503635191553,
0.3910772647246715,
0.39400632306393685,
0.4109357393771207,
0.4163410915311307,
0.41816459971235165,
0.42252764144480326,
0.43347380456325807,
0.435696281748153,
0.44301634426481185,
0.453481768706172,
0.46307154320261923,
0.4691677512037378,
0.46934557070509453,
0.4736100446708187,
0.4764587668478003,
0.4914682078649019,
0.49708883552851807,
0.4989653008464718,
0.5011285370045405,
0.5098189247039806,
0.5209596336702528,
0.5278237946925293,
0.5501036890701407,
0.5551041026696315,
0.5593579433255046,
0.5614983229767005,
0.5617926864659308,
0.5655289412257961,
0.5802908272771363,
0.5889310183452419,
0.6006524589952945,
0.624822034287017,
0.6302801026102428,
0.6498155436414438,
0.6711314255389402,
0.7097413148908829,
0.7279695179821742,
0.7805217243317325,
0.8095861819199952,
1
], 10))
```

Comment: That did it! One more bug: it doesn't include the last number of the dataset. I figured the last element of `ranges` should be incremented one last time before returning. This is a bit of a grey area tho, because technically it would fail the conditions.

Comment: Fix #2: sometimes the returned array would have less elements than requested because the cells would be empty. The array would also contain "empty" cells.  
Adding `ranges.push(0);` before `for (n=0; n<dataset.length-1; n++)` fixed it.

Comment: You're right. Because we already know the length of the array, i think it'll be better if we create a 0 filled array with `new Array(numranges).fill(0)` from the begining.

Answer (score 0):

Use either of the following solutions to create ranges from an array. The range starts from minimum and ends to maximum number in an array. Let me know if this is working!

```js
// sample array that needs to be divided into n ranges
const arr = [10,20,34,20,50,76];

//1. Calculate min and max of array
const min = Math.min(...arr);
const max = Math.max(...arr);

//2. Calculate ranges in [[10, 20], [20, 30], [30, 40]] format
const getRangeArray = (min, max, n) => {
  const delta = (max - min) / n;

  const ranges = [];
  let range1 = min;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
    const range2 = range1 + delta;
    ranges.push([range1, range2]);
    range1 = range2;
  }

  return ranges;
};

const rangeArrayIn3Parts = getRangeArray(min, max, 3);
console.log("Divided range array into 3 parts", rangeArrayIn3Parts);

//2. Calculate ranges in [10, 20, 30, 40] format
const getRange = (min, max, n) => {
  const delta = (max - min) / n;

  const ranges = [];
  let range1 = min;
  for (let i = 0; i <= n; i += 1) {
    ranges.push(range1);
    range1 += delta;
  }

  return ranges;
};

const rangeInto10Parts = getRange(min, max, 9);
console.log("Divided range into 10 parts", rangeInto10Parts);
```